# how to embed the whole html file into JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement an online chat functionality on 3 of my websites, but I dont want to copy paste my whole code on every website. I want to create something like `tawk.to` has. They just have a `<script>` tag and we paste a tiny code on our page and the whole functionality is rendered through JS.

Right now I have it in an HTML file, where my logic is in JS in the same HTML file.

Something like this?

```
<script src="path-to-my-file.js"></script>
```

Basically in my page's  tag I will include this JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
<script src="loads-html-from-other-place"></script>
</body>
```

Here is what tawk.to does:

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var         
s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/12341/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

You just paste this code in your page and it displays chat box along with the functionality

Comment: I don't know what `tawk.to` is, but from your description, it sounds like they're just dynamically creating the elements of the page using JS. Do you know about DOM manipulation? `document.createElement` and the like?

Comment: Its little bit more complex I think. Want you 3 separate chats room or should all 3 websites include the same chat room?

Comment: "I don't want to load html  I want to load it through JS".  Wut?  At some point you're going to have html that includes a script tag, or has the script embedded in it.  I'm not understanding this statement.

Comment: @Taplar I think it's talking about having a script that generates HTML to insert into the DOM rather than static markup

Comment: @raulxbox your tawk.to example pretty much answers your own question. Seems like you already know how to do it?

Comment: explain what you want kiddoo.

Comment: You will find all answers in [Third Party Javascript book by Manning](https://www.manning.com/books/third-party-javascript) as question is a bit too broad and I could not suggest somothing more concrete.

Comment: explain what you want kiddoo.

Comment: edited my question. I want to insert another JS source from which this html will be created

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by below approach.

```
....
</body>
<script src="path-to-my-file.js"></script>
```

Create a JS file

```
IN that file write a logic to create chat button.
That file can have click events of that button which is added at run time VIA ajax.
You can then include this file in all the HTML pages where you need chat functionality.
Make sure you load this file at the end of body tag.
```

Comment: Same thing i also suggested in my comment as per your question.